# JDK7 generics not compiling

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, java-7

The following code compiles in jdk6 but not in jdk7. Please suggest any workarounds

```
public interface LocalCacheMap<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>  
extends ClearableCache<K>, Iterable<V>{
    V get(K key);
}

public class Universe<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V, TSKEY extends Comparable<? super TSKEY>> extends MasterLocalCache<K>  
implements Iterable<V>, LocalCacheMap<K, V>, TsDaoInfo<TSKEY, K>, ValueConverter<K, Object, V>{
    public V get(K key) {
        return get(key, keyFunct);
    }
    abstract public TSKEY buildTsKey(K key, Date date);

    abstract public K getObjKey(TSKEY tsKey);

    abstract public Date getDateKey(TSKEY tsKey);

}

public class JdbcTimesSeriesCacheDef<K extends Comparable<? super K>, TSKEY extends Comparable<? super TSKEY>, LC extends Universe<K,?,TSKEY>&DataSourceProvider, T> extends AbstractRawTimeSeriesCacheDef<K, T, LC> {
    private final SqlDefs<T> defs;

}
```

When compiling with jdk7, I am getting the following error

JdbcTimesSeriesCacheDef error: get(K#1) in Universe cannot implement get(K#2) in LocalCacheMap

Comment: It'd sure be nice to have something that *we* could compile too...

Comment: There were many dependent classes and its hard and cumbersome to provide all these classes.

Comment: So...stub them out.  Get a minimal working example.  We can't see the same compilation failures you are if you don't provide something that compiles, too.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
LC extends Universe<K,?,TSKEY>&DataSourceProvider,
```

to

```
LC extends Universe<K,T,TSKEY>&DataSourceProvider,
```

Comment: I can't use T.. since its not the appropriate type. class Universe<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V, TSKEY. it must be value type 'V'

Comment: What is there now (?) means that JdbcTimeSeriesCacheDef doesn't care what type it is.  Can you use Object instead?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using specific Value type 'V' in place of "?"

public class JdbcTimesSeriesCacheDef, V, TSKEY extends Comparable, LC extends Universe&DataSourceProvider, T> extends AbstractRawTimeSeriesCacheDef {
    private final SqlDefs defs;

}